# my firebase recyclerview only picks first data from list when any list is clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to pick the data from a particular list in firebase recyclerview anytime it is clicked. when you click a particular list item at a particular position, it should give you the corresponding data. but anytime i click the list, it only gives me the first data not matter which position in the list i click, it still gives me the first data.

This is my main activity code

```
package com.example.helpresponse;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private RecyclerView FindFriendsRecyclerList;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");
        FindFriendsRecyclerList = findViewById(R.id.find_friends_recycler_list);
        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                        .setQuery(UsersRef, Contacts.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, FindFriendViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        holder.userMessage.setText(model.getMessage());
                        holder.userLongitude.setText(model.getLongitude());
                        holder.userLatitude.setText(model.getLatitude());

                        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view)
                            {
                               // TextView myMessage = findViewById(R.id.user_message);

                                TextView myLongitude = findViewById(R.id.user_longitude);
                                TextView myLatitude = findViewById(R.id.user_latitude);


                              //  TextView descriptionEditText = findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
                                String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();
                                String longitudeInfo = myLongitude.getText().toString();
                                String latitudeInfo = myLatitude.getText().toString();


                                Intent profileIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", visit_user_id);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("user_long", longitudeInfo);
                                profileIntent.putExtra("user_lat", latitudeInfo);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, longitudeInfo + latitudeInfo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(profileIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder(view);
                        return viewHolder;
                    }
                };

        FindFriendsRecyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userMessage, userLongitude, userLatitude;

        public FindFriendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_message);
            userLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_longitude);
            userLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_latitude);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my fragment:

```
package com.example.helpresponse;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private View ContactsView;
    private RecyclerView myContactsList;

    private DatabaseReference ContacsRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;


    public ContactsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        ContactsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);


        myContactsList = ContactsView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        myContactsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        //currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


        ContacsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");


        return ContactsView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                        .setQuery(ContacsRef, Contacts.class)
                        .build();


        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder> adapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ContactsViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ContactsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
            {
                final String userIDs = getRef(position).getKey();

                UsersRef.child(userIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        {
                            /*
                            if (dataSnapshot.child("userState").hasChild("state"))
                            {
                                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                                String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                                String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();


                                if (state.equals("online"))
                                {
                                    holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                else if (state.equals("offline"))
                                {
                                    holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                holder.onlineIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }



                             */
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                            {
                                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                                String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                                String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();


                                holder.userMessage.setText(message);
                                holder.userLongitude.setText(longitude);
                                holder.userLongitude.setText(latitude);

                                // Picasso.get().load(userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image).into(holder.profileImage);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue().toString();
                                String longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                                String latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();


                                holder.userMessage.setText(message);
                                holder.userLongitude.setText(longitude);
                                holder.userLongitude.setText(latitude);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ContactsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                ContactsViewHolder viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };

        myContactsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }




    public static class ContactsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView userMessage, userLongitude,userLatitude;
        //CircleImageView profileImage;
        ImageView onlineIcon;


        public ContactsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            userMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_message);
            userLongitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_longitude);
            userLatitude = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_latitude);
           // profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
            //onlineIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_online_status);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/find_friends_recycler_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of code in here. It's best if you can isolate the problem. For example, is the `String visit_user_id = getRef(position).getKey();` inside your click listener not giving you the key of the clicked item? Is `position` the value of the item you clicked on?

Comment: @Frank, it gives the key correctly. but it doesnt give the correct corresponding data in that particular key. it only gives the first data as default for any list you click

Comment: So in the line of code I commented on, the value of `visit_user_id` is correct for the value of `position`? If so, what specific line of code that you shared does *not* do what you expect it to do? Note that all I'm doing here is trying to pinpoint where the problem is. Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to tell us very clearly what part of the code (not of your app) doesn't do what you expect from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `View.OnClickListener`, you shouldn't be searching for displayed elements by ID and instead use the `holder` variable to access the child elements of the current item.

Change

```java
// TextView myMessage = findViewById(R.id.user_message);
TextView myLongitude = findViewById(R.id.user_longitude);
TextView myLatitude = findViewById(R.id.user_latitude);
```

to

```java
// TextView myMessage = holder.userMessage;
TextView myLongitude = holder.userLongitude;
TextView myLatitude = holder.userLatitude;
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much @Samthecodingman. it worked. i really appreciate the help. thank you!